# javafx how fill grid with random colors

Tags: java, javafx

I have a grid. 
Now the background of the grid is lightGray. 
But how can I get the background of the grid with random colors? So not one color.

How can I make this?

Can someone help me?

thanks in advance.

the code is:

```
public class Grid2 extends Application {

    double gridSize = 20;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
      Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        scene.setFill(createGridPattern());
    }

    public ImagePattern createGridPattern() {

        double w = gridSize;
        double h = gridSize;

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(w, h);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        gc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        gc.setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.2));

        gc.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        gc.strokeRect(0, 0, w, h);

        Image image = canvas.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
        ImagePattern pattern = new ImagePattern(image, 0, 0, w, h, false);

        return pattern;

    }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably add a new Jpanel() object of each cell of your grid to get a different color. By making different component of group of some specific cells or just even one cell, you can have different background color for the same.

Comment: Can you give a example how to do this?